# Check if string is starts with letter or not in angular js?

Tags: angularjs, validation, modal-dialog, angular-filters

> I am working with modal form. I have to make sure that entered string starts with letter otherwise i have show error message.

```
<section class="col-md-12">  
 <div data-ng-controller="coursesCtrl">
    <script type="text/ng-template" id="add_course.html">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <h3>Create Course</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <form name="course_form" role="form" class="form-horizontal form-validation" novalidate data-ng-submit="ok(course_form.$valid, courses.single)">
            <fieldset>
              <div class="form-group"  ng-class="{'has-error' : course_form.title.$invalid && (!course_form.title.$pristine || submitted) }">
                <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3">
                  <label for="title">Title</label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-9 col-md-9 col-sm-9">
                  <input type="text"
                   class="form-control"
                   id="title"
                   placeholder="Title of the course"
                   data-ng-model="courses.single.title"
                   required name="title"
                   ng-Maxlength="45"
                   >
                </div>

                <div class="help-block col-lg-offset-3 col-sm-9 col-md-offset-3 col-md-9" ng-show="course_form.title.$invalid && (!course_form.title.$pristine || submitted)"> Title is required or it is taking more than 45 characters. 
                </div>                     
              </div>

            </fieldset>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button class="btn btn-default" id="create_course">Create</button>
            <button class="btn btn-default" ng-click="cancel()">Close</button>
          </div>
        </form>    
      </div>
    </script>   
     <button class="btn btn-primary pull-right"ng-click="open('lg')"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span> Create Course</button>   
</section>
```

> How can i validate the title field. Could any one know how to solve it. Please let me know.
>   Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds like a typicall task for a regular expression.

You can check your model inside your controller with this:

`courses.single.title.match(/^[A-z].*/)`

I would also wrap it within a condition, so that an empty input doesnt throw the validation error.

Comment: But the string can accept number except first letter @Charminbear

Comment: My Regexp only checks the first letter (`^[A-z]`), the rest can be anything (`.*`)

Comment: Why not use `ng-pattern`?

Comment: I am using ng-pattern="/^[A-z].*/" in my app. it fixes my issues @runTarm